# Read pdf file with HTML5 File API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to make a form with React and upload pdf files. I've to implement until here but now my app needs to read data from pdf without saving in backend database etc. The whole functionality works as pre-checker.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried anything that we can check and assist with ?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can use PDF.js [link](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) to read a pdf file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use PDF.js to read the content of PDF file using javascript/jQuery. Here is my working example.

```js
$("#file").on("change", function(evt){


var file = evt.target.files[0];

//Read the file using file reader
var fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = function () {

//Turn array buffer into typed array
var typedarray = new Uint8Array(this.result);

//calling function to read from pdf file
getText(typedarray).then(function (text) {

/*Selected pdf file content is in the variable text. */
$("#content").html(text);
}, function (reason) //Execute only when there is some error while reading pdf file
{
alert('Seems this file is broken, please upload another file');
console.error(reason);
});

//getText() function definition. This is the pdf reader function.
function getText(typedarray) {

//PDFJS should be able to read this typedarray content

var pdf = PDFJS.getDocument(typedarray);
return pdf.then(function (pdf) {

// get all pages text
var maxPages = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;
var countPromises = [];
// collecting all page promises
for (var j = 1; j <= maxPages; j++) {
var page = pdf.getPage(j);

var txt = "";
countPromises.push(page.then(function (page) {
// add page promise
var textContent = page.getTextContent();

return textContent.then(function (text) {
// return content promise
return text.items.map(function (s) {
return s.str;
}).join(''); // value page text
});
}));
}

// Wait for all pages and join text
return Promise.all(countPromises).then(function (texts) {
return texts.join('');
});
});
}
};
            //Read the file as ArrayBuffer
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.87/pdf.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept="application/pdf">
<br>
<p id="content"></p>
</body>
```