# How can I scrape PDF created using PDF.js using selenium?

Tags: selenium, pdf, web-scraping, pdf.js

I have successfully managed to download the PDF file from a site that uses PDF.js to create and show PDFs (using selenium)

The downloaded PDF file does not open on my desktop (mac & linux).

It seems like the PDF is encoded, or encrypted.

On closer inspection, right after the PDF is downloaded, the network tab also shows pdf.js.worker. It seems like pdf.js.worker is decoding this file to show on the site.

[image: Network tab > .pdf and pdf.js.worker]

How can I replicate, or follow the same flow of pdf.js.worker and decode this PDF?

**Update**

I have tried looking at the pdf.js.worker code to follow the code execution, but it seems like a really hard task, hoping there is a simpler way.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the pdf.js.worker code?

Comment: @CP3O  Yes but the code is huge and it seems almost impossible to do a trace and follow the execution all the way, hoping there is a simpler solution

Comment: Any idea if something like this would work?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054746/read-pdf-file-with-html5-file-api/52055678#52055678

Installing PDF.js and then just passing the PDF file to it locally.

Comment: No idea, I think someone else will have to weigh in on this.